# Server Error in '/park' Application when changing name servers

Tags: asp.net, linux, dns, server

I have looked through the documentation here and I feel like I am missing something here. A friend changed his name servers on GoDaddy. I did not see what he did, but he is getting this error:

```
Server Error in '/park' Application.

No such host is known

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

Source Error: 


Line 140:        }
Line 141:
Line 142:        if (InRange(System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(_parkedDomainProvider.Value.DomainName).AddressList[0].ToString()) == false)
Line 143:        {
Line 144:            Response.Clear();

Source File: d:\Sites\CDS\cds\controllers\page-controller.aspx.cs    Line: 142 

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
   System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +6666430
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +106
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress) +109
   CDSPageControllers_page_controller.get_DocumentRoute() in d:\Sites\CDS\cds\controllers\page-controller.aspx.cs:142
   Atlantis.Framework.Web.CDSContent.CDSContentPageControllerBase.WhiteListCheck() +39
   Atlantis.Framework.Web.CDSContent.CDSContentPageControllerBase.OnPreInit(EventArgs e) +28
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +37
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1104

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1087.0
```

I am unfamiliar with this happening after changing name servers and I am unclear as to whether he may not have flushed dns, or something else because I see ASP.NET being referenced at the bottom and this site is supposed to point to a linux server.

Comment: How long ago did he change the name servers?

Comment: Like 10 minutes ago, can this just be part of the propagation process? Is this what you are getting at?

Comment: Yes...DNS updates can take a little while. I'd wait 24 hours before I raise the alarm.

Comment: @mason, DNS propagation was my first guess, but my buddy was really concerned and entrusted me to look into it and I have never seen this error before, because when I do nameserver changes I let it do its thing. Thank you. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take 24-48 hours for DNS to propagate to all DNS servers. So some may still be pointing to the old server.

It looks like the host has some sort of "parking" landing page on the server, and that it has an error. Since that parking application is in ASP.NET and your application is not ASP.NET, it's not yours to worry about.

I'd check again in a few hours and see if it's pointing to the correct location.